# Power BI - one slicer (child table) affect options other slicer (different child table)

Tags: powerbi, parent-child, slicers

I have a userform with selection slicers to filter data through several pages with table visuals.
I have two seperate groups of slicers, both filtering their own table. These tables are connected through a single parent table.
If I select options in the slicers, these limit the options available in the rest of the slicers for that table. However selecting data in the slicer of one of the tables doesn't affect the slicers from the other tables.

I'll try to explain.
My data consists of measurements. Each measurement has GeneralTest data, stored in the parent table. Each test is performed on a specific valve and actuator. The valve and actuator have specific data, stored in child tables and connected to the GeneralTest table.

If I select for instance a 4" valve from the Size slicer, I would like the Type slicer from the actuator table to update to only show the actuators that have been combined with the 4" valve. For some reason it does filter the keys from all three tables (if I put these in a table visual), but doesn't update the selection options of the slicers from the other child table.
If I select an actuator that doesn't match with the 4" valve, I get no results, but that means the user has to know which size actuator matches with which size valve to get all required results.

Long story short, is there a way to limit the options on slicers connected to a different child table from the slicer that has been selected?